# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) EnterpriseMaster/BindNatureofAssignment: not working after publish

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

code is working good in localhost but when i publish this code error get and not loading table
EnterpriseMaster/BindNatureofAssignment:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

```
              var post = $http({
              method: "POST",
              url: "/EnterpriseMaster/BindNatureofAssignment",
              dataType: 'json',
              headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" } });
              post.success(function (data, status) {
                  //The received response is saved in Customers array.
                  $scope.NAO = data;
              });
```

Answer (score 0):

404 error occurs means,Please check the action BindNatureofAssignment is occur in controller or not, if its present Please assign  a base url for javascript variable and give that javascript variable to

```
 var ApplicationPath = 'Path of your Application';

var post = $http({
          method: "POST",
         url:  ApplicationPath+"/EnterpriseMaster/BindNatureofAssignment",
          dataType: 'json',
          headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" } });
          post.success(function (data, status) {
              //The received response is saved in Customers array.
              $scope.NAO = data;
          });
```